# Show and hide element using css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an unordered list element contains list of elements like this.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="menu-x">x1</li><li class="menu-x">x2</li><li class="menu-x">x3</li>
<li class="menu-y">y1</li><li class="menu-y">y2</li><li class="menu-y">y3</li>
<li class="menu-z">z1</li><li class="menu-z">z2</li><li class="menu-z">z3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And in the css when using `display: inline;`.it is not showing or hiding the particular element.So this is my css.

```
div.menu li{
  display: inline;
  border-radius:2px;
  font-size:12px;
  margin:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0px 5px #FFFFFF;
  padding:7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
li.menu-y{
  display:none;
}
li.menu-z{
  display:none;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp43hbhs/) is here

Comment: you can use float:left instead of display:inline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `display: none` has no effect because the earlier selector `div.menu li` is more specific and so it takes precedence. Change the selector to something like `div.menu li.menu-y`.

The selector `div.menu li` has a specificity of 012 because it has 1 class selector and 2 element type selectors as part of it whereas the `li.menu-y` and `li.menu-z` selectors have a specificity of only 011 because it has only 1 class selector and 1 element type selector as part of it.

Changing the selector to `div.menu li.menu-y` would mean that the specificity becomes 022. Thus, it it will take precedence over `div.menu li` and so the `display: none` will take effect.

Or even `.menu li-menu-y` would be sufficient because its specificity is 021 (2 classes and 1 element type) but I prescribed the other because I felt it was more consistent with your earlier selector.

```css
div.menu li {
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 5px #FFFFFF;
  padding: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
div.menu li.menu-y {
  display: none;
}
div.menu li.menu-z {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-x">x1</li>
    <li class="menu-x">x2</li>
    <li class="menu-x">x3</li>
    <li class="menu-y">y1</li>
    <li class="menu-y">y2</li>
    <li class="menu-y">y3</li>
    <li class="menu-z">z1</li>
    <li class="menu-z">z2</li>
    <li class="menu-z">z3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
div.menu li{
  display: inline;
  border-radius:2px;
  font-size:12px;
  margin:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0px 5px #FFFFFF;
  padding:7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
.menu .menu-y{
  display:none;
}
.menu .menu-z{
  display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/jp43hbhs/1/)

Comment: It is great that you have a solution but you should have a valid reason for that!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
ul li .menu-y {
  display:none;  
}

ul li .menu-z {
  display:none;  
}
```